# Llamar a una función desde un botón en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy tratando de llamar a una función de mi controlador en Laravel desde mi vista pero no puedo, actualmente cree la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::post('nuevo','NameController@metodo')->name('nuevo');
```

Este sería mi botón:

```
<button href="{{action('NameController@metodo') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Accion</button>
```

Luego en mi `Namecontroller` tengo la siguiente función:

```
public function metodo(){
    //Mi insert DB
}
```

Lo único que deseo es cuando haga click en el botón se ejecute el `insert` que tengo en mi método Nuevo, traté de hacerlo con `action` pero claramente no es correcto ya que no hace nada, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar una etiqueta `a` adentro de tu botón y llamar a la ruta que ya has creado que está ligada a tu método

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="{{ route('nuevo') }}">Acción</a></button>
```

Como a tu ruta le pusiste nombre "nuevo" puedes utilizar ese nombre en la etiqueta `a` aunque yo le pondría un nombre un poco más distintivo, por lo menos `nuevo.metodo`.

Tanto tu ruta como tu método son correctos.

Comment: cuando lo ejecuto me muestra https:/127.0.01/nuevo (yo no tengo una vista tengo es un insert) luego despliega el siguiente mensaje Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: Ok, pero entonces ¿Por qué creaste una ruta `Route::post('nuevo','NameController@metodo')->name('nuevo');`? El primer argumento, donde dice `'nuevo'` es la ruta que se utilizará, si deseas llamar el método desde tu página principal entonces usa `/`. Con la información que había en la pregunta es fácil asumir que tienes una vista `nuevo` ya que la utilizas en las rutas.

Comment: Route::post('/','NameController@metodo'); asi? gracias por la ayuda, puse un intento de lo que he tratado perdon si fue confuso el mensaje

Comment: El primer argumento adentro de los paréntesis es la ruta desde donde estás llamando la función, desconozco desde qué parte de tu aplicación estás intentando llamarla pero por ejemplo, si tuvieras una ruta `https:/127.0.01/datos` entonces la ruta debería ser `Route::post('/datos','NameController@metodo');`. Ahora, desconozco el motivo por el que desees utilizar `post`, por lo que veo no lo necesitas, así que un `get` tal vez sería suficiente, dependerá de tu aplicación.